# Azure:How to copy partitioned data from from data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The folder structure on my data lake is /raw/project/countryName/year/files.json
How can I create a copy activity to read all files in each folder?

In the documentation I could only find partitioned by data example:

```
"folderPath": {
      "value": "adfcustomerprofilingsample/logs/marketingcampaigneffectiveness/@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStartTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd')}/",
      "type": "Expression"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"folderPath": {
      "value": "/raw/project/countryName/@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStartTime, 'yyyy')}/",
      "type": "Expression"
},

Specify your folderPath as above, and don’t specify your fileName.
In your copy source typeProperties, set recursive as true.

Comment: The thing is counryName is many folders  like "BE", "NO", "FI" , "US"

Comment: Currently ADF only support filter of fileName with wildchar for file share dataset. So in your case, maybe you could use foreach + copy activity. Make all your countryName as items, and in folder path, reference @item() to construct folderPath. You could reference this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

Comment: Like:"folderPath": { "value": "/raw/project/@{item()}/@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStartTime, 'yyyy')}/", "type": "Expression" },

Comment: do you know how to do the same in V1 data factory?

Comment: V1 doesn't have foreach and parameters. I think you have to create multiple copy activity to implement it.

Comment: what if the year value is also an array like 2002...2018? I guess here you assumed the startDate value takes only one single date

Comment: each item could be an object. You could put both country and year in an object.

Comment: forEach iterates on items array and now it is ["BE", "NO", "FI" , "US"] and forEach loops only 4 times. How can I combine years as array into country?

Comment: In my opinion, to avoid two loops, you may need combine the two dimensions yourself. Like [{"country":"BE", "time": "2001"}, {"country": "No", "time": "2002"}]. You could use item().country, and item().year to refer them seperately. And you could also store these meta data to a table, and then use lookup activity to get this data. Then use foreach to iterate the output of lookup activity.